# What is equivalent of group by and collect as list in elastic search?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an elasticseach index

```
{class_id: 1, student_id: 10}
{class_id: 2, student_id: 20}
{class_id: 1, student_id: 30}
{class_id: 2, student_id: 40}
```

I want an aggregation such that

```
{class_id: 1, student_ids: [10,30]}
{class_id: 2, student_ids: [20,40]}
```

Not sure how to go about it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to use two `terms` aggregations, like this:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "classes": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "class_id"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "students": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "student_id"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You'll get one bucket for each class and inside each class bucket, you'll get one bucket per student in that class.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. You get `classes` buckets with the keys 1 and 2, and within each you get `students` buckets with keys 10, 30, respectively, 20, 40. Exactly what you asked for, or did I miss something?

Comment: sorry about that, let me try that and I will get back to you. Thanks for your help!